# Why so many interactive console icons in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I use Eclipse on Mac OS X for some Python projects and noticed that there were a pretty large number of interactive console icons:

[image]

What could be the cause and how can I reduce the number of interactive console icons ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Humm, this seems like a bug for me (only a single entry is actually expected there). Please report this at: https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/

Comment: Thanks, done, ticket #708 https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/708